# different NodePort range for different Kubernetes users?

Tags: kubernetes

I am running a Kubernetes cluster with quite a few users, it has happened several times that the NodePorts from different users conflict. Is it possible in Kubernetes to set different NodePort ranges for different users? Just like the --service-node-port-range with kube-apiserver, but this is for all the users not for specific user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dynamic kubernetes port range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324199/dynamic-kubernetes-port-range)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is similar to [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324199/dynamic-kubernetes-port-range) and the answer will be same. It is not possible. You will have to communicate port ranges to your users and then check their deployments for enforcing the ranges, before actually deploying.

Comment: It's also worth adding, the answer really is to _not_ use NodePorts. This is what Ingress exists for.